# CloudBlockBlob.DeleteAsync throws exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I'm trying to delete a blob snapshot - I don't want to delete anything other than the snapshot for which I have the reference.

```
await snapshotBlob.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.None,
                                       acc,
                                       new BlobRequestOptions(),
                                       new OperationContext());
```

I've tried different `DeleteSnapshotsOption` but the exception tells me that only `DeleteSnapshotsOption.None` can be used when deleting a snapshot.

The `AccessCondition` (`acc`) has only the `LeaseID` set.

I don't have `BlobRequestOptions` or `OperationContext` preferences; I've also tried passing `null` for those two properties but it makes no difference.

The method call throws "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Stack trace:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.EndDelete(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at StorageHooks.StorageBackup.d__0.MoveNext() in [*line in my
>   code*]

Can anyone explain what's wrong with the way I'm calling the method?

Also, in case it has an influence, I'm calling this method in an Azure Function. Furthermore, the code is copying existing blobs into another container, and the code works for creating a snapshot, creating the new blob, uploading to the other container, copying metadata, obtaining a lease... The only part which fails is deleting the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and traced the request/response through Fiddler. When I specified the lease id in the access condition, I got the 400 error. When I looked up the details, this is what the error message told me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Error>
        <Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
        <Message>
            Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
            RequestId:cb8bcb1d-001e-004a-4811-991d8e000000
            Time:2018-01-29T15:00:02.6030417Z
        </Message>
        <QueryParameterName>snapshot</QueryParameterName>
        <QueryParameterValue>2018-01-29T14:55:27.3537780Z</QueryParameterValue>
        <Reason>Leases are not allowed with snapshots.</Reason>
    </Error>
```

Please try your request by removing the access condition from your request. When I did that, the request went just fine. So your code would be:

```
await snapshotBlob.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.None)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Wouldn't it be tremendously useful if that 'Reason' was propagated into the exception message?  Also, there isn't an overload of `DeleteAsync` which accepts only the `DeleteSnapshotsOption` enum, but `DeleteAsync()` works.

Comment: `Wouldn't it be tremendously useful if that 'Reason' was propagated into the exception message?` - It does actually. Please take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.storageextendederrorinformation?view=azure-dotnet.